# Using the Criteria API and Metamodel API to Join two Middle table always cross join

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

This is a RBAC module,There is three basic table user,role and permission and middle mapping table user_role and role_permission.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER") 
public class User implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private String userId;
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE") 
public class Role implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private String roleId;
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERMISSION") 
public class Permission implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private String permissionId;
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_ROLE") 
public class UserRole implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuidGenerator", strategy = "uuid")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuidGenerator")
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "USERID")
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ROLEID")
  private Role role;
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE_PERMISSION") 
public class RolePermission implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "PERMISSIONID")
  private Permission permission;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ROLEID")
  private Role role;
  ...
}
```

and now i want to find all permission by user.id, SQL express like this:

```
 select rp.* from Role_Permission rp,User_Role ur where ur.roleId = rp.roleId and ur.userId = :id
```

but by Criteria API:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<RolePermission> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
            if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(userId)) {
                final Root<UserRole> userRoleRoot = criteriaQuery.from(UserRole.class);
                Join<RolePermission,UserRole> join = root.join("role", JoinType.INNER);
                Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("roleId"), root.get("role").get("roleId"));
                predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate,criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoleRoot.<UserRole>get("user").get("id"), userId));
                predicates.add(predicate);
            }
            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
        }
```

and query build result is:

```
select count(rolepermis0_.id) as col_0_0_ from role_permission rolepermis0_ inner join role role2_ on rolepermis0_.roleid=role2_.roleid cross join user_role userrole1_ where role2_.roleid=rolepermis0_.roleid and userrole1_.userid=?
```

but why here role_permission cross join user_role, how role_permission join user_role by criteria API ?

thanks a lot.

Comment: For a start your JPQL is invalid. You do a JOIN on a relation, not on a class. So start with "select rp from RolePermission rp inner join rp.role r". Use that to decide what Criteria to use

Comment: JPQL just a fake code.and I really just need find is RolePermission,SQL express like this: select rp.* from RolePermission rp,UserRole ur where ur.roleId = rp.roleId and ur.userId = :id

Comment: Firstly if it is "fake code" then don't post it. Secondly if you want to add a Predicate (the "criteriaBuilder.equal") you should use the "join" not "root.get().get()". Also if you only have the relation in RolePermission then that needs to be your "candidate" in the Criteria ... is it ???

Comment: should use the "join"? your mean "Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("roleId"), join);" ?

Comment: Looking at your model again, and that SQL you now post ... your SQL implies CROSS JOIN. Also you have no way of specifying INNER JOIN in JPA since there is no relation between UserRole and RolePermission (since JPQL and Criteria work from relations), so the join between those classes can only be CROSS JOIN also

Comment: yes, UserRole and RolePermission has no direct relation, but i think there both has a Role as ManyToOne and there should be inner join together. Last and important,Could you tell me how to join "UserRole" and "RolePermission" as sql expression by criteria API . THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

```
 final Subquery<UserRole> userRoleSubquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(UserRole.class);
 final Root<UserRole> userRole = userRoleSubquery.from(UserRole.class);
 userRoleSubquery.select(userRole.<UserRole>get("id"));
 userRoleSubquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("role").get("roleId"), userRole.get("role").get("roleId")), criteriaBuilder.equal(userRole.get("user").get("id"), userId));
 Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.exists(userRoleSubquery);
 predicates.add(predicate);
```